# How to upload file using many to many field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models. One is article and other is documents model. Document model contains the filefield for uploading document along with some other metadata of uploaded document. Article has a m2m field that relates to Document Model. Article model has a field user according to which article is being which article is being posted.

I want to upload file using m2m field, but it gives two errors:

***"files": [
"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received InMemoryUploadedFile."]***

I also tried using slug field, the document does not exists. but i am uploading new file then why saying document does not exist.

Please guide me how i can achieve this?

Article Model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="ARTICLE_ID")
    headline=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    abstract=models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    content=models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    files=models.ManyToManyField('DocumentModel', related_name='file_documents',related_query_name='select_files', blank=True)
    published=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags=models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='tags', blank=True)
    isDraft=models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    isFavourite=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", blank=True)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=mode
```

Document Model

```
class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name="DOCUMENT_ID")
    document=models.FileField(max_length=350,  validators=[FileExtensionValidator(extensions)], upload_to=uploaded_files)
    filename=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    filesize=models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    mimetype=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Article Serializer

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


   #serializer for getting username of User
    created_by=serializers.CharField(source='created_by.username', read_only=True)
    isFavourite=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    tags=serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Tags.objects.all(), slug_field="tag")
    readtime=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    

    class Meta:
        model= Article
        fields = ["id" , "headline", "abstract", "content", "readtime", "get_published_timestamp",  "isDraft", "isFavourite", "tags", 'files',  'created_by'  ]
```

Document Serializer

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    filesize=serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='sizeoffile')
          
    class Meta:
        model=DocumentModel
        fields = ['id', 'document', 'filesize', 'filename', 'mimetype', 'created_at' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add files to M2M fields, because M2M fields hold objects of other models.

If you have a M2M of `DocumentModel`, it will only accept the objects of `DocumentModel`. It only expects the primary keys of `DocumentModel` objects.

To upload files, you can use a `FileField` instead.

Comment: agreed i searched alot, couldnt find a way ...